# Convergence of a telescoping series divided by another series

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that the sum from $k=1$ to $k=n$ is $$\frac{n+1}{2n+4}.$$Find the sum from $k=1$ to $k=\infty$ of ${a_k}/k$.

Since $a_n=s_n-s_{n-1}$, I get $$a_k=\frac{k+1}{2k+4}-\frac{k}{2k+2}, k\geq2.$$

Therefore the sum from $k=1$ to $\infty$ for $a_k/k$ is $$\frac{1}{3}+\lim\left(\frac{k+1}{2k^2+4k}-\frac{k}{2k^2+2k}\right).$$

I'm not sure where to go from here. Any suggestions? I thought it would be a scoping series, but it doesn't seem to be once $a_k$ is divided by $k$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Using your method, and simplifying a bit, we find that
$$\frac{a_k}{k}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{(k)(k+1)(k+2)}\right).$$
This series also telescopes. We find that 
$$\frac{a_k}{k}=\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{k(k+1)}-\frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)}\right).$$

Comment: Thank you for the partial fraction idea.That makes total sense. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. Note that this generalizes, $\frac{1}{k(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)\cdots(k+m-1)}$ telescopes.